# php flush() sometimes not work, reloading the page it works

Tags: php, flush

I don't understand the problem in my code, I suppose it is something related to `flush()`
It sometimes works, sometimes not, but if I reload the page,
(then click "continue" on confirm form submission popup), it works!

Here's my code:

**Class.php:**

```
private function myFunUpdate($aaa, $bbb, $ccc, $ddd, $eee){
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($aaa, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($httpCode == "200"){
        $percent = @round($ccc/$bbb, 2) * 100;
        if ($percent > $this->_percentDownloaded){
            $this->_percentDownloaded++;
            echo '<script>myFunUpdate("'. $percent .'");</script>';
            ob_end_flush();
            ob_flush();
            flush();
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.php:**

```
<?php
    if ($_POST['submit']){
        echo '<div><img src="http://example.com/img'.$alpha->stuff1(trim($_POST['myURL'])).'.jpg" /></div>';
        echo '<div>'.$alpha->stuff2(trim($_POST['myURL']), 'url').'</div>';
        echo '<div id="progressBar">0%</div>';
        flush();

        if ($alpha->stuff3(trim($_POST['myURL']))){
            echo '<div id="divSuccess"></div>';
            echo '<script>var progressBar = document.getElementById("progressBar"); progressBar.style.width = progressBar.innerHTML = "0%"; updateProgress("'.trim(strstr($alpha->myFun(), '/'), '/').'");</script>';
            flush();
            $alpha->stuff4($_POST['param1']);
        }else{
            echo '<p>Error, something was wrong...</p>';
        }
    }
?>
```

And in php log file I find this (referring to the **Class.php** lines):

```
PHP Notice:  ob_end_flush(): failed to delete and flush buffer. No buffer to delete or flush in xxx.php on line xxx

PHP Notice:  ob_flush(): failed to flush buffer. No buffer to flush in xxx.php on line xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be the cause, from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/es/function.ob-flush.php)

> If you call ob_flush() and flush() and still dont get the buffer
>   flushed it might be because some antivirus software (Panda in this
>   case) holds the buffer until the page has finished loaded before
>   sending it to the browser.

Also it seems to be important to include the header at the beginning of your php code:

```
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
```

Ok, with your code I would try:

```
private function myFunUpdate($aaa, $bbb, $ccc, $ddd, $eee){
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($aaa, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($httpCode == "200"){
        $percent = @round($ccc/$bbb, 2) * 100;
        if ($percent > $this->_percentDownloaded){
            $this->_percentDownloaded++;

            // start output buffering
            if (ob_get_length() === false) {
             ob_start();
            }
            echo '<script>myFunUpdate("'. $percent .'");</script>';

            while (ob_get_level()) {
             ob_end_flush();
            }
        }
    } }
```

and

```
<?php
    header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
    // start output buffering
    if (ob_get_length() === false) {
      ob_start();
    }
    if ($_POST['submit']){
        echo '<div><img src="http://example.com/img'.$alpha->stuff1(trim($_POST['myURL'])).'.jpg" /></div>';
        echo '<div>'.$alpha->stuff2(trim($_POST['myURL']), 'url').'</div>';
        echo '<div id="progressBar">0%</div>';

        while (ob_get_level()) {
            ob_end_flush();
        }

        if ($alpha->stuff3(trim($_POST['myURL']))){
            // start output buffering
            if (ob_get_length() === false) {
              ob_start();
            }
            echo '<div id="divSuccess"></div>';
            echo '<script>var progressBar = document.getElementById("progressBar"); progressBar.style.width = progressBar.innerHTML = "0%"; updateProgress("'.trim(strstr($alpha->myFun(), '/'), '/').'");</script>';
            while (ob_get_level()) {
               ob_end_flush();
            }
            $alpha->stuff4($_POST['param1']);
        }else{
            echo '<p>Error, something was wrong...</p>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I have to place it at the beginning of Index.php, Class.php, or both?

Comment: index.php ( before including class.php )

Comment: ok, I will tell you after many tries if it works ok? Thank you for help :)

Comment: Sorry, I did many tries, but it seems not solve my problem... sometimes I have the error...  it is driving me crazy.. I'm spending all the day trying to fix it...

Comment: Please can you tell me in alternative how to simulate the page reload automatically? I really need to make it working in any way, please

Comment: Actually seems that using JS `document.location.reload(true);` I am able to reload the page resubmitting the form, in this way it works.. I echo this script in the index.php else statement... But it looks like a very bad solution :(

Comment: I agree with you, hope you find a better solution. I'm afraid I'm unable to help you. Maybe it's some sort of missconfiguration of  the apache or php settings, could be?

Comment: Coulde be... I'll check.. Thank you for your time vivoconunxino :)